# How can I enable composer to have command line argument auto complete?

Tags: bash, composer-php

I would like to be able to use tab auto completion with composer in my bash shell, the same way I can for example auto complete filenames or git commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable auto complete for `composer` in bash you need to write a function that returns an array of possible values for the last typed parameter (`_composer()` in this case) and register it using `complete -F function command`.

As a complete, working example add the following to your `.bashrc` (or any other configuration script you might be using)

```
_composer()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local cmd=${COMP_WORDS[0]}
    if ($cmd > /dev/null 2>&1)
    then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$($cmd list --raw | cut -f 1 -d " " | tr "\n" " ")" -- $cur) )
    fi
}
complete -F _composer composer
complete -F _composer composer.phar
```

Comment: This didn't work as I was expecting, I was expecting to be able to type composer update w<tab> and see all packages installed beginning with w. Instead I just get a list of files/directories in my current terminal directory?

Comment: Yup, this only autocompletes the commands, not the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since composer 2.4 (August 2022), [bash completion is supported](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#bash-completions) almost out of the box. It can be configured like so:

> To install bash completions you can run `composer completion bash > completion.bash`. This will create a `completion.bash` file in the
> current directory.
>
> Then execute source `completion.bash` to enable it in the current
> terminal session.
>
> Move and rename the `completion.bash` file to
> `/etc/bash_completion.d/composer` to make it load automatically in new
> terminals.